# Polymer: paper-menu-button do not close when paper-action-dialog opens

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a paper-menu-button and in the same page a paper-action-dialog. Like that:

```js
    function openDialog() {
        document.querySelector('#dialog').toggle();
    };
```

```html
<script src="//www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dialog/paper-action-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dropdown/paper-dropdown.html">
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
    
<paper-action-dialog id="dialog" heading="Dialog Title" backdrop>
    <p>Some content</p>
    <paper-button dismissive>More Info</paper-button>
    <paper-button affirmative>Decline</paper-button>
    <paper-button affirmative>Accept</paper-button>
</paper-action-dialog>
    
<button type="button" onclick="openDialog()">Click Me!</button>

    <br/> <br/>
    
<paper-menu-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" noink></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
        <core-menu class="menu">
            <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
        </core-menu>
    </paper-dropdown>
</paper-menu-button>
```

When I click to open the menu-button and don't close it and click on the button to open the action-dialog, the menu-button remains open. I tried to close it with:

```
document.querySelector('core-overlay-layer').opened = false;
```

and with:

```
$('core-overlay-layer').removeClass('core-opened');
```

but the core-overlay do not close correctly this way and if you try to open de menu-button again, on the first click it will close the last menu-button open that was hidden.
What is the correct way to close the menu-button before open the action-dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been seen in the documentation of the component: paper-menu-button.

```
overlayListeners: {
  'core-overlay-open': 'openAction',
  'core-activate': 'activateAction'
},

activateAction: function() {
  this.opened = false;
}
```

So I would do:

```
    function openDialog() {
        document.querySelector('#dialog').toggle();
        document.querySelector('paper-menu-button').opened = false;
    };
```

As opened is a property of the entire element.